# CSS bug in Safari but not Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

https://gist.github.com/2354116

If you view the above page in Chrome/Firefox then everything seems to be fine. The divs at the bottom (the two headings and the social icons) are wrapped in a container div and center without issue.

If it's viewed in Safari though then these three divs are not centered at all :/

I'm not sure why this is.... can anyone help?

Comment: Looks OK in Windows Safari 5.1.5

Comment: [No URL shorteners please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113658/no-url-shorteners). Include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: im using the Mac version... strange..

Comment: I'm not on my home machine, otherwise I would check the Mac version too.

Comment: it's also not centered on IE7-8...

Comment: @Keva161 you've posted your page before and i keep telling you that you're not properly utilizing the bootstrap grid system properly. The problem why is not aligning its because your buttons are overflowing your span container. Your buttons are `width:150px` plus a 10px padding and your `span2` containing them is 140px by default (170 on the responsive sheet).

Comment: @ Andres llich .. even with the code as http://jsfiddle.net/rzSFa/ it will still not centre

Comment: @Keva161 its not that part, its your complete page layout that needs to be rewritten to utilize the bootstrap grid system, that is quite an effort. Question, are you utilizing the responsive bootstrap sheet at all?

Comment: @Keva161 also, what is the actual width of your main container? I see multiple widths and no proper containment in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** had to assume a lot with your design so modify anything that does not fit your original design.

First off, you are not properly containing your page elements (content, carousel, footer), you currently have multiple width containers trying to reside side-by-side and that is breaking your design in multiple places.

Your content container is `width:940px`, your `.wrapper` div is `width:750px`, your `.paramWrapper` div is `width:870px`, your `.carousel` div is `width:735px`. You have to pick one width and stick to it and just use margin to push content accordingly across your page. I used `860px`, which is the width of the `span11` class.

Next, you're modifying the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet directly, that means that whenever the bootstrap gets updated all of your changes will be lost if you overwrite the bootstrap stylesheet, so create a another stylesheet and put all of your custom styles there and just load it "after" the bootstrap stylesheet in your header.

Now onto your original issue, the bottom `.paraWrapper` div is not properly stacking because you have a width of `870px` set in your container and the elements within do not add up to that width:

`span3` + `span3` + `span2` + margin = `640px`

So it was not an issue or a bug, its just your layout.

Here is a fixed version that i very quickly put up so you're going to have to modify the elements to fit your design once again: http://jsfiddle.net/rzSFa/3/, here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzSFa/3/show/) of what it looks like.

By the way, you're using the responsive bootstrap stylesheet for naught, it is currently not doing much in your case so why even use it? You can easily modify a few media queries to support my fixed version though, but yours will not work at all because you're declaring all of your own classes with custom widths so there is no point in including it.